# Possible to reference variables from lambda functions?

Tags: serverless-framework

Is it possible to reference variables defined in `serverless.yml`?

For example in a Node lambda, something like:

```
writeToDynamoDb(${self:custom.dynamoDbTableName})
```

I'm using the serverless-webpack plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if my understand is right, there is no need extra serverless plugin to do the job.

Use nodejs as sample.

Suppose you have below setting in `serverless.yml`

```
custom: 
  dynamoDbTableName: myDB
```

Then define the environment variable `dynamoDbTableName` to one lambda function in `serverless.yml`

```
functions:
  createTodos:
    handler: handler.create
    environment:
      dynamoDbTableName: ${self:custom.dynamoDbTableName}
    events:
      - http:
          path: todos
          method: post
          cors: true
```

Then you should be fine to reference this variable by below way in handler.js:

```
const dynamodb =  process.env.dynamoDbTableName
```